# Should a dupehammer grant the ability to dupe to multiple questions?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, dupehammer

Currently when a moderator or gold tag badge holder closes a question as a dupe, they are limited to duping it to just one question. However, when several users vote to close the question, you can end up having a question closed as a dupe of two or more separate questions.

In some cases it would be beneficial if **moderators and gold tag badge holders could include more then one question when closing as a dupe**, if more then one question would better answer the question. On the [Sci-Fi and Fantasy stack](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) we run into this issue occasionally; other stacks may not face this issue.

Comment: If it's a duplicate to multiple questions, it's quite a big sign that maybe it's not actually duplicate of anything, those multiple questions should already be duplicates in some way, the question is too broad, or anything else awry. Closing as a duplicate of multiple questions should be rarely necessary, if ever.

Comment: How about leaving a comment so others can start the dupe voting, and you acknowledge with your hammer?

Comment: @rene that is what we currently do, but that can leave the question open for longer then necessary.

Comment: If only there was another exact duplicate of this question...

Comment: Perhaps the ability to mark a single question as a duplicate of multiple others [is a CM power](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289393/whats-allowed-for-sockpuppets?noredirect=1&lq=1)? Or perhaps [Shog has just trifurcated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289395/278659).