# Too many Shogs when viewing the close reason in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, ios-app

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289393/242209) appears to have been closed by three Shogs:

> [image: Close bug]

Does this happen when a mod closes a question as a dupe of multiple questions?

- App Version: 1.6.3 (TestFlight)
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Maybe the first two are his sockpuppets.  Oh the irony.

Comment: @Jamal I guess we found out what happened to shogs 1-8.

Comment: I'm voting to close Shog9 as a duplicate.

Comment: How can the SockPuppets of Shog be Mods too? Wow.

Comment: Shog9♦ Overflow

Comment: THERE ARE NEVER TOO MANY SHOGS. ALL HAIL SHOG'S SOCKS.

Comment: Not sockpuppets. I voted for that post three times using one account, carefully triggering a server error half-way through the processing of the first two votes so as to add multiple duplicate links. *Hopefully*, we'll have a better process for that at some point in the future.

Comment: @Shog9 I figured they weren't all separate accounts.  Care to add that as an answer?

Comment: I'll leave answering for Brian and Kasra, since Marc helpfully fixed the display in these cases for web years ago.

Comment: Thanks, @Shog9.  And may the dupes be ever in your favor.

Comment: I'll just drop [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284729/should-a-dupehammer-grant-the-ability-to-dupe-to-multiple-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1) (relevant) link here.

Comment: @randal'thor Added an answer to the dupe target about this being available to mods or SE employees: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289404/242209

Comment: Is Stack Exchange ready for Shog27?

Comment: All three votes show up in the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=289393&filter=!bA1d)xkZJnXJPj&site=meta&run=true and we're reflecting that back.  Guess it should be fixed there.

Comment: @BrianNickel Right.  This was fixed on the web, and I guess the next question is should it be fixed on every client (iOS, Android, etc) or fixed at the origin on the server?  Sounds like this has been an issue since 2009.

Comment: @Shog9 That mean, someone using the same bug as you could close any question by spending 5 votes on it? Does that work for upvoting too? If so, is there anything preventing malicious users from abusing it?

Comment: There's a check that prevents ordinary users from casting multiple close votes on a given post, @Magisch; this only works because moderators are exempt from that check. Up/down votes are a completely different path.

Comment: I, for one welcome our @Shog9 clone overlords

Comment: This. Is. EPIC!!!!

Comment: @Jamal Not sockpuppets, they're *Shog9-puppets*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next API build.  (Monday?)

We were missing a `.Distinct()` call.

Comment: Will accept on Monday once I verify the fix is in place.  Thanks!

Comment: We'll miss all those Shogs. :)

Comment: And here I was thinking there was an easteregg where one can unlock additional shogs :(

Comment: @JAL Update is live.

Comment: Thanks.  Aww, I will miss all those shogs.